# Apache shows error 500 instead of php errors

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I was given a virtual host to upload my projects but my project is not working for some reason when uploaded and I can't debug the code because the server is not displaying any php errors and instead it redirects me to the default error 500 page. My senior told me to google how to fix this and refuses to help me whatsoever. I found other threads on here but all those include setting up the `php.ini` file for which I don't have access. I have also found and tried doing the trick with .htaccess using the lines below but those didn't help me.

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag  log_errors on
```

I uploaded a `phpinfo()` file to see what are the settings for error displaying and of course there is that:

```
Directive                Local Value    Master Value
display_errors           Off            Off
display_startup_errors   Off            Off
```

So the only thing that comes to my mind is fixing this with the php.ini but again, I can't access this file. Is there any other way to activate error reporting on apache with a php code or .htaccess file that I don't know of?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can turn on error reporting in PHP:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

Read more about the constants used for the `error_reporting()` function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).